# Python Spark - Remove data after threshold - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How do I remove data after the last `TP == 1` with a buffer of 48 hours?

For example `ID = A9`, the last `TP == 1` is on `2020-05-06 13:00`. I want to keep all the data for that group of IDs up to `2020-05-06 13:00` where the last `TP == 1` plus the next 2 days?

```
+---++--------+----------------+
| id|       TP|            Date|
+---+---------+----------------+
| A1|     Null|2010-01-01 12:00|
| A1|     Null|2010-01-01 13:00|
| A1|        1|2010-01-02 01:00|
| A1|     Null|2010-01-02 02:00|
| A9|     Null|2010-05-05 12:00|
| A9|        1|2010-05-05 13:00|
| A9|        1|2010-05-06 13:00|
| A9|     Null|2010-05-09 13:00|
+---+---------+----------------+
```

**Desired Dataframe**

```
+---++--------+----------------+
| id|       TP|            Date|
+---+---------+----------------+
| A1|     Null|2010-01-01 12:00|
| A1|     Null|2010-01-01 13:00|
| A1|        1|2010-01-02 01:00|
| A1|     Null|2010-01-02 02:00|
| A9|     Null|2010-05-05 12:00|
| A9|        1|2010-05-05 13:00|
| A9|        1|2010-05-06 13:00|
+---+---------+----------------+
```

This is what I am doing in Pandas, but it is not efficient for 15M+ observations

```
main_pd = main.toPandas()

bigdf = pd.DataFrame()

for i in main_pd.ID.unique():
  df = main_pd[main_pd.ID == i]
  TPdate = df[df.TP == 1]['Date'].max()+pd.Timedelta('3 days 0 hours')
  df = df[(df.Date <= TPdate)]
  bigdf = bigdf.append(df)
```

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/expedia-group-tech/deep-dive-into-apache-spark-window-functions-7b4e39ad3c86) should help you get what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can use Window function to find `max(IF(TP=1, Date, NULL))` over each `id` and then filter by this threshold value:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F
w1 = Window.partitionBy('id')

df_new = df.withColumn('Date', F.to_timestamp('Date', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')) \
    .withColumn('threshhold_date', F.expr("max(IF(TP=1, Date, NULL))").over(w1)) \
    .filter('Date <= threshhold_date + interval 2 days') 
df_new.show()
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|  TP|               Date|    threshhold_date|
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| A9|Null|2010-05-05 12:00:00|2010-05-06 13:00:00|
| A9|   1|2010-05-05 13:00:00|2010-05-06 13:00:00|
| A9|   1|2010-05-06 13:00:00|2010-05-06 13:00:00|
| A1|Null|2010-01-01 12:00:00|2010-01-02 01:00:00|
| A1|Null|2010-01-01 13:00:00|2010-01-02 01:00:00|
| A1|   1|2010-01-02 01:00:00|2010-01-02 01:00:00|
| A1|Null|2010-01-02 02:00:00|2010-01-02 01:00:00|
+---+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply filter the dataframe for `TP = 1`, and use `collect()[0]` to get the maximum value of the `Date` column as a variable.
Add 48 hours to this variable using `timedelta` and filter your `df`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from datetime import timedelta

date_var = df.filter(col("TP")==1).orderBy("date", ascending=False)\
                .collect()[0]["date"] + timedelta(hours=48)

df.filter(col("Date")<=date_var).show()
```

Comment: Oh it was about partitions. I misunderstood the question.